# PythonOcc: Thicken a curve with variable radius

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphics, computational-geometry, opencascade

I am new to pythonOcc, I want to thicken a Bezier Curve (or make a pipe) unevenly: for example, the resulting thickened curve at the start point of the curve should be thicker than at the endpoint of the curve. 
Could you let me know what is the most efficient way to do that? I've tried functions like BRepOffsetAPI_ThruSections, but I don't think there are useful for this purpose.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Could you let me know what is the most efficient way to do that? I've tried functions like BRepOffsetAPI_ThruSections, but I don't think there are useful for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it, it can easily be done using the module: BRepOffsetAPI_MakePipeShell. 
Wires can be added as profiles and the "setlaw" method can be used to vary the thickness of the profile.